# fabric.js background image type 'rectangle' not recovering

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I'm trying to store a fabric.js canvas with a background image type `rect`. On recovery the background image wont show up.

Here is a jsfiddle demonstrating the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/revpz6qw/

After clicking "save and restore" the background is blank instead of yellow.

I can't find the problem.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

It does not recover because the background is supposed to be of type Image or simply a color.
It is rendering on add because the function does not take in consideration the type of object that you are passing. But the restore function does not handle it.

Alternatively you can place an object as first object and set its property evented to false.

```
rect.scaleWidth(canvas.getWidth());
rect.scaleHeight(canvas.getHeight());
rect.evented = false;
canvas.add(rect);
```

Comment: ah, I see. So there is no way to use "objects" like a rectangle as background? (What I wanna do is, to change the background color in just a part of my canvas . I could do it by using a png or svg. I just need one color, so I thought it should be possible with usage of an rectangle object)

Comment: ah, alright, I guess may answer came at the same time as your edit. I'll try your soloution asap.

Thanks for your support.

Comment: So, your solution solves part of the problem for me. The thing is, other objects in the canvas could disappear behind the object with `evented = false` set when using the `sendBackwards()` function.

Comment: Perhaps than you have to listen for layer changes and account for this. At the very least, slam your desired background to back as a last step every time.